# Export list ESM from JSON

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I would like to export a list using ESM from a JSON object. Let's say I have the following object:

```
const myList = {
    func1: function(){},
    func2: function(){}
}
```

And would like to export it such as:

```
export {myList.func1 as func1, myList.func2 as func2}
```

Is there a nice way to export all the functions (assuming we have a lot more functions) in `myList` such as each function inside it can be imported with its name (e.g. `import {func1} from './myList.js'`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) There is no such thing as a "JSON object". JSON is always a `string`; if it's an `object`, it's Javascript. JSON also cannot store functions.

That being said, you can make use of [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) here:

```
export { func1, func2 } = myList;
```